# Timestamp minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, timestamp

I'm using SQL Server and I need to SELECT timestamp that return only data on every full hour. So now I get:

```
timestamp                  value
2019-12-18 17:00:00.000    0
2019-12-18 17:05:00.000    0
2019-12-18 17:10:00.000    0
2019-12-18 17:15:00.000    0
2019-12-18 17:20:00.000    1,5
2019-12-18 17:25:00.000    1,5
2019-12-18 17:30:00.000    0
2019-12-18 17:35:00.000    0   
2019-12-18 17:40:00.000    0 
2019-12-18 17:45:00.000    0
2019-12-18 17:50:00.000    0
2019-12-18 17:55:00.000    0
2019-12-18 18:00:00.000    0,6
```

but i need

```
timestamp                  value
2019-12-18 17:00:00.000    0
2019-12-18 18:00:00.000    0,6
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
SELECT timestamp ,
       value
FROM   myTable 
WHERE  DATEPART(MINUTE, timestamp) = 0;
```

If you want to check that the seconds and milliseconds are 0 too:

```
SELECT timestamp ,
       value
FROM   myTable
WHERE  DATEPART(MINUTE, timestamp) = 0
       AND DATEPART(ss, timestamp) = 0
       AND DATEPART(ms, timestamp) = 0;
```